# increment a string in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

How would you increment every character in a string by 3? 
I'm actually new to assembly and i don't know much about it :/ 
I have a code that takes STRING input and displays the output to the user on the screen

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

  STR1 DB "ENTER YOUR STRING : $"
  STR2 DB "YOUR STRING IS : $"
  INSTR1 DB 20 DUP("$")
  NEWLINE DB 10,13,"$"

.code
main proc

Mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

    LEA SI,INSTR1

;Get STRING

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,STR1
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,0AH
    MOV DX,SI
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,NEWLINE
    INT 21H

;PRINT STRING


    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,STR2
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,INSTR1+2
    INT 21H

     MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,NEWLINE
    INT 21H


mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Let's say if user writes 'HELLO' so the output i want is to be 'KHOOR'. So how would i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert next loop after the comment `;PRINT STRING` :

```
    ADD SI, 2             ;◄■■ SI : POINTER TO STRING.
INCREMENT:
    MOV AL, [SI]          ;◄■■ GET CURRENT CHAR.
    CMP AL, 13            ;◄■■ IF CHAR IS END OF STRING
    JE  INCREMENT_END        
    ADD AL, 3             ;◄■■ INCREASE CHAR BY 3.
    MOV [SI], AL          ;◄■■ PUT CHAR BACK INTO STRING.
    INC SI                ;◄■■ MOVE TO NEXT CHAR.
    JMP INCREMENT         ;◄■■ REPEAT LOOP.
INCREMENT_END:
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question :) But the above code is not working :/

Comment: The cursor keeps blinking. It's not displaying any OUTPUT. All it shows is 'Enter Your STRING : HEllO ' line and nothing else :(

Comment: @zubaida12, this is what I'm doing : I copy all the code in **your question**, paste it in my compiler, then I copy the code in **my answer**, paste it **after `;PRINT STRING`**, then I run it and it prints "'KHOOR".